# android: problem sending mail, SuperNotCalledException thrown

Tags: android, email

While sending mail from a button's click my device shows an error. Which throws SuperNotCalledException in logcat

I am posting the code and the logcat output here.

Code

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
      android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String recosubject = getString(R.string.recoSub);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ""
      + recosubject);

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ""
      + reco);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
```

And here is the logcat output

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-29 15:29:14.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6823): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
12-29 15:29:14.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2461)
12-29 15:29:14.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
12-29 15:29:14.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
12-29 15:29:14.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6823):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
12-29 15:29:14.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6823):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 15:29:14.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6823):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-29 15:29:14.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4367)
12-29 15:29:14.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6823):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 15:29:14.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6823):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-29 15:29:14.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6823):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-29 15:29:14.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6823):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-29 15:29:14.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6823):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anybody tell what is going wrong in this code?

Comment: can u post your onCreate method too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution my self.... It was merely a silly mistake, thanks to Marcovena and Saurabh for point it out. +1 for both of them.

This is what I have done as change

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
      android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String recosubject = getString(R.string.recoSub);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ""
      + recosubject);

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ""
      + reco);
```

Instead of this line

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
```

I changed this

```
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

And it worked.

Thanks to both of you guys to point this silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In your onCreate method of ChooseActivity add this as first line

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: This line is already there my friend, I think it is something about email activity......  If in case you want to see here is a snippet

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.socNetAndMail);......

Comment: is the above snippet from chooseactivity class

Comment: There is a class called SocNetAndMail.java which extends activity and have four buttons, twitter, fb ,linkedin and send mail.... this snippet is from send mail button's onclick event.

Comment: If you look at logcat 2nd line its saying that the ChoooseActivity is the class from where the error is getting so I think you must look in onCreate of this Activity

Comment: 1. I do not have any choose activity. 2. I think if you see the package level, it seems to be an internal activity of android.

Comment: hmm, you are correct  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
 whats the purpose of above line

Comment: to start the activity of sending the mail... I got this code from forums.

Comment: I think change intent to emailIntent as there is nothing in intent I suppose

Answer (score 1):

> startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
>   What is the difference b/w *emailintent* and *intent* variables? or is it just a typo?

Comment: No this line is to start the activity... actually i got this code in almost every blog and forums. So I use this code..